# Removing index.php in codeigniter -htaccess

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Im trying to remove index.php from the url for the past 4 days but not successful.

**http://domainName.com/CI/index.php/controller-name/function/parameter**

CI is the folder hosted in godaddy.

/
.htaccess
CI

After googling, I tried with the following codes but getting only a blank page or error:500 and also I didn't understand the logic. Please someone help me to find where Im going wrong.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[Javascript / CSS / Image root Folder name(s)]|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

2nd

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I also changed the line in, CI/application/config/config.php

> $config['index_page'] = '';
>
> $config['uri_protocol'] = “REQUEST_URI”

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783666/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-rewrite-issues/14807463#14807463

Comment: How to allow override(apache.conf) in godaddy server.. Nothing works in my server.  My base_url is http://domain.com/ci/

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ CI/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: in your example you haven't used RewriteBase to set it to CI folder since in that folder your application resides. Here is an example in setting RewriteBase dynamically. It might be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062290/set-rewritebase-to-the-current-folder-path-dynamically

Comment: Even adding RewriteBase/ CI  ..It doesn't work, any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Just try this it's working means reply me**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: just save this in your ht access file and try

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work ..  No input file specified.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following step:

1. Change the config file like this:

   $config['index_page'] = '';

   $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
2. Use the following .htaccess:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Note: .htaccess vary depending on server. Some server (e.g.: Godaddy) need to use the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

[see here](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/109912/profile)

Use the following code in base_url:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 's' : '').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace('//','/',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']).'/');
```

Comment: After changing allow ovveride in apache.conf it works fine in localhost..Still issue not solved in godaddy server, it display "No input file specified. ".. When placing ur htaccess code the url domainName.com/CI/index.php/controller-name/function/parameter changes into domainName.com/?/controller-name/function/parameter... Any help .!!

Comment: You need to use the last .htaccess for godaddy. It is a special case.

Comment: Do i need to inckude the folder name ci in the htaccess code u mentioned above

Comment: No you do not need to include any directory name. It supposed to work perfectly.

Comment: No input file specified :-(  ... But it works fine in localhost

Comment: Could you please share your .htaccess file once again here. And please also let me know you base_url text.

Comment: Now Im exactly using the 2nd htaccess code you mentioned above.. base_url is   http://domain.com/ci  and  
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

Comment: Even this doesn't work .. previously there are two .htaccess file in my server.  one in public_html/.htaccess and another in public_html/htaccess/.htaccess ( I deleted this). Any other changes do I miss.

Comment: We have a pull of hosted web application done with Codeigniter and run in godaddy server without any hassle. I can't realize your case without seeing the directory structure, file structure etc.